# XINT0 - AVR simulator behaves unexpected / unpredictable

Tags: assembly, external, interrupt, avr, simulator

In my ATTiny13 application, ExtInt0 did not respond as expected, so I started debugging (simulator in AVR Studio7, no stimuli file). To reduce complexity, I stripped my code to the absolute minimum.

```
; TstExtInt0.asm
;

.include "tn13def.inc"

;------------------------------------------------------
;register definitions
;------------------------------------------------------
.def    StatReg =   r2
.def    TmpReg  =   r16
.def    WaitReg1 = r20
.def    WaitReg2 = r21
.def    Flags_Reg =   r23

;------------------------------------------------------
;constants
;------------------------------------------------------
.equ    _KEY_FLAG_BIT0    =   0

;------------------------------------------------------
;interrupt vectors
;------------------------------------------------------
.org    0x0000  rjmp RESET                ;Reset
.org    0x0001  rjmp KeyPressed           ;ISR detecting button being pushed
.org    0x0002  reti; rjmp PCHINT               ;ISR Pin Change Interrupts
.org    0x0003  reti; TIM0_OVF             ;Timer0 Overflow Interrupt
;------------------------------------------------------
;Main programme - Init
;------------------------------------------------------
RESET:  ldi     TmpReg, RAMEND            ;Stack
        out     SPL, TmpReg

        ;----------------------------------------------
        ;prepare port B
        ;----------------------------------------------
        ldi        TmpReg, (1<<PB1)|(1<<PB2)|(1<<PB3)|(1<<PB4)|(1<<PB5)
        out        ddrb, TmpReg             ;set PortB bit 0 as input, PortB bit 1 to 5 as output
        ldi        TmpReg, (1<<PB1)|(1<<PB2);set 'Enable' 
        out        PortB,TmpReg             ;and transfer to the output pins


;----------------------------------------------
;ExtInt0 init
;----------------------------------------------
        ldi         TmpReg,0x40                 ; enable ExtInt0 
        out         GIMSK,TmpReg

        sei                                     ; enable interrupts

; Initialise register values
;       ldi         T0Cycles, 0             ; reset
        ldi         Flags_Reg, 0            ; reset 

;------------------------------------------------------
; Main loop
;------------------------------------------------------
IdleKey:
        ldi     TmpReg, 0x07     ;just LEDs as indicator
        out     PortB, TmpReg
        ldi     TmpReg, 0x19
        out     PortB, TmpReg
        sbrs    Flags_Reg, _KEY_FLAG_BIT0   ; idle here as long as key not pressed / flag not set, 
; _KEY_FLAG_BIT0 in FlagsReg is set by ISR KeyPressed (Ext Int0)
        rjmp    IdleKey                     ; otherwise, key has been pressed 

idlePB0: sbis  PinB,0                       ; keep checking if PortB0 is still low, idle if necessary until level is high again
        rjmp    idlePB0                     ; otherwise
        ldi     Flags_Reg, 0                ; reset Flags_Reg again

        rjmp   IdleKey
;------------------------------------------------------
;end main loop
;------------------------------------------------------

;------------------------------------------------------
;ExtInt0 Interrupt: key is pressed
;------------------------------------------------------
KeyPressed:
        cli                         ; disable all interrupts
        in      StatReg,SREG        ; save status register
        ldi     TmpReg, 0x00
        out     GIMSK, TmpReg       ; in particular disable INT0 - for the moment don't detect further pulses (debouncing)
        ori     Flags_Reg, 0x01     ; set flag for key pressed
        out     SREG,StatReg        ; reload status register
        reti
```

When running the simulator, I observe the following behaviour: stepping through the code instruction by instruction, XINT0 / ISR KeyPressed never is activated (as expected when not manipulating PB.0). However, re-running the simulator on his own ('continue' button), 7 or 8 cycles later I end up at the breakpoint at the start of my ISR 'KeyPressed' (regardless at which cycle counter / instruction I continued).

To make things more confusing: I have an old laptop with AVR Studio4 running. Here, the simulator consistently jumps the first time he arrives at the line

`rjmp    IdleKey                        ; otherwise, key has been pressed`

to the .org 0x0001 statement, and, hence, to the ISR.

In none of both environments, the simulator shows the ExtInt Flag in register GIFR being set, though.

Is this a bug in the simulator or is there something I do not understand regarding interrupt handling or usage of the simulator? - Thanks for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues present. One in confusion on whether or not an interrupt should be firing, and one in Atmel Studio settings.

---

The statement "as expected when not manipulating PB.0" when referring to the external interrupt `INT0` is incorrect. The `INT0` pin is `PB1` which you have as an output which is sometimes set high in your code. Your assumption seems to be that `INT0` exists on `PB0`.

---

Not having interrupts fire during stepping is an intentional feature in Atmel Studio 7 (and possibly other versions), allowing for code to be debugged without presumably arbitrarily-timed external interrupts messing with the flow of the code.

This can be disabled in `Tools -> Options -> Tools -> Tool settings -> Mask interrupts while stepping`.

This seems to either not be a feature, or not be enabled by default, in Atmel Studio 4, which is why you see it process the exception when expected.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Embarrassing that I mixed up Int0 PCInt0 and their respective port pins. Sorry for wasting others time. (This also explains why the original code didn't work.) Regarding simulator behaviour: very much clarifying! This is what I felt - something I do not understand... (Great community!!)